# Route to LAN subnet via OpenVPN client

Tags: linux, openvpn, route

I am trying to route to a LAN subnet that is connected via an OpenVPN client.

I am having trouble with the `route` command - I cannot make sense of it. The OpenVPN link is established and I can `ping` the client.

When I try to add a route to the LAN subnet on the VPN server, I get this error:

```
# route add -net 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.9.0.6 dev tun0
SIOCADDRT: No such process
```

The routing table for the **OpenVPN server** has `10.9.0.0/24` in it, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

```
# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         ve108.csr2.lga1 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.9.0.0        10.9.0.2        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
10.9.0.2        *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
204.145.81.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

More information:

```
# ip ad sh
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0e:cf:20:c1:24 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 204.145.81.11/24 brd 204.145.81.255 scope global eth0
    inet6 fe80::20e:cfff:fe20:c124/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN qlen 100
    link/none 
    inet 10.9.0.1 peer 10.9.0.2/32 scope global tun0
```

Considering that I can `ping` the VPN client I am trying to route to, I don't understand why I am having this problem. As far as I know I should just be able to add the route.

```
# ping -c 1 10.9.0.6
PING 10.9.0.6 (10.9.0.6) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.9.0.6: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=24.0 ms

--- 10.9.0.6 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 24.008/24.008/24.008/0.000 ms
```

Here is the details from the **OpenVPN client**, which is connected to the VPN server. The network I am trying to route to is on this client.

```
# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         greece-gw.secus 0.0.0.0         UG    2      0        0 eth0
10.9.0.1        10.9.0.5        255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun0
10.9.0.5        *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
loopback        localhost       255.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 lo
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
198.50.241.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

It can reach the VPN server fine:

```
# ping -c 1 10.9.0.1
PING 10.9.0.1 (10.9.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.9.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=24.0 ms

--- 10.9.0.1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 24.017/24.017/24.017/0.000 ms
```

It has IP forwarding enabled:

```
# sysctl -a | grep forwarding
net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding = 1
```

I've set `iptables` to allow forwarding:

```
# iptables -nvL FORWARD
Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  tun0   eth1    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Here is the config for the interfaces on the client:

```
# ip ad sh
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:5f:f2:1e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 198.50.241.113/24 brd 198.50.241.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe5f:f21e/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:c6:b8:fd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.2/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fec6:b8fd/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: sit0: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN 
    link/sit 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
5: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN qlen 100
    link/none 
    inet 10.9.0.6 peer 10.9.0.5/32 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: Your trying to add a gateway (10.9.0.6) that is only accessible via a gateway (10.9.0.2). Did you add the 10.9.0.0/24 route manually? Can you add the output of `ip ad sh`?

Comment: The route to 10.9.0.0/24 is right there in the table.

Comment: # route add -net 10.9.0.0/24 gw 10.9.0.2
SIOCADDRT: File exists

Comment: Sorry, I was asking if you were manually adding that route to the client.. not if it was there, which I could see =)

Comment: Something doesn't line up with the interfaces you are posting. The 10.9.0.5 interface doesn't exist on the server for the 10.9.0.6 client. And you are routing to 10.9.0.0/24 via a 10.9.0.2 tunnel interface. Is there an additional client involved?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately network tools often have horrible error messages. As far as I can tell, what the kernel doesn't like is that you are trying to add a route with a gateway that it doesn't see as being "local". You should either do:

```
route add -net 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.9.0.2 dev tun0
```

or:

```
route add -net 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 dev tun0
```

In adition to configuring the kernel route you will also need to add a route inside openvpn itself. This is done by using the "iroute" directive in the ccd file for the client.

Answer (score 0):

Stumbling-upon this question while conducting another search, it appears that the OP is trying to access a *subnet* that is attached to a remote OpenVPN server.

My reply assumes *tunnel* mode, not *bridged* mode.  (OpenVPN is acting as a *router*, not a *switch*.)

If my understanding is correct, then a `--client-config-dir` ("CCD") must be used in this case.  There must be a `route` directive covering the subnet's address-range in the main configuration, *and* an `iroute` (notice the "i") in a CCD file that will be correctly identified as belonging to *that* remote. (You will see whether or not it is recognized by looking at the OpenVPN logs, and then by confirming that a route now exists on your machine.)

If you are accessing the subnet from another subnet *(i.e.* not from the machine that's running the OpenVPN client, there must *also* be a static route within your local subnet which sends traffic to your OpenVPN machine "as a gateway."  This could be defined on each client machine or, more conveniently, on the local router.

And here's how the traffic will flow:

- You ping the remote subnet.
- Your machine or your router forwards the traffic to your OpenVPN box as a gateway. *(Because, functionally, an OpenVPN tunnel acts as a router.)*
- The `route` directive on that machine causes the traffic to be sent into the `tunX` device so that OpenVPN actually gets it.
- The `iroute` directive (and the CCD in which it occurs) tells OpenVPN that a remote subnet exists, and which remote to send it to. *(Even if there is only one remote.)*
- The traffic is routed to the destination on the remote side.
- *And now, it all has to happen in reverse!*  The remote sends the ping-reply using your IP-address on the remote subnet, and it has to make its way *all the way back* home.

If you ping from a machine that is directly connected to OpenVPN *(it is running the client)*, then your address will probably be `10.8.0.x` and *this* address-range also must be successfully routed, "there and back again," on all devices concerned.

These are "basic TCP/IP routing issues," which would be the case whether "the router in question" is OpenVPN or not. Once you get the hosts to successfully talk to one another *(yay!)*, "to the network, they're just routers."

`tcpdump` (or WireShark) and `traceroute` are your best friends here.  First, you must ensure that the encrypted traffic is being delivered as it should be among the OpenVPN hosts. *(Even though of course you can't read their content, you can see them being routed, or not.)* Then, do the same things within the tunnel. See that the packets are delivered to and through the tunnel, and that they make it all the way there *and* back.  (If `traceroute` starts printing rows of asterisks, it probably means that there is no *reverse* routing at that particular "hop." The packet makes it there but can't get home from there.)